# SQL - SUM of the for max ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table like this,

```
| id | name | subtask | maintask |
|----|------|---------|----------|
| 1  | t1   | 11      | 20       |
| 1  | t1   | 12      | 20       |
| 1  | t1   | 1       | 30       |
| 2  | t1   | 2       | 20       |
| 2  | t1   | 2       | 20       |
```

I want to prepare a result like this

```
| id | name | sum_of_subtask | sum_of_maintask | diff |
|----|------|----------------|-----------------|------|
| 2  | t1   | 4              | 40              | 36   |
```

Need to pick the max ID, then do the sum for subtask and maintask, then the last column is the difference of sum(subtask) and sum(maintask)

I tried this below query, but its calculating the sum for all the columns.

```
select max(id), name, sum(subtask),sum(maintask),sum(subtask-maintask) from tbl
group by name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want one row?  If so, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id, name, sum(subtask), sum(maintask), sum(subtask-maintask)
from tbl
group by id, name
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

If your data is large, it might be more efficient to filter *before* aggregating:

```
select id, name, sum(subtask), sum(maintask), sum(subtask-maintask)
from tbl
where id = (select max(id) from tbl)
group by id, name;
```

If you want the maximum `id` per `name`, then the filtering logic is:

```
select id, name, sum(subtask), sum(maintask), sum(subtask-maintask)
from tbl t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from tbl t2 where t2.name = t.name)
group by id, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select id, name, sum(subtask), sum (maintask), sum(subtask)-sum (maintask)
where id in
(select max(id) from table)
group by id, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, sum(subtask), sum(maintask), sum(subtask-maintask)
from tbl
where id = (select max(id) from tbl)
group by id, name
```